# Count lines in files of type *.cpp and *.h only

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell

I have already following bash script. It count lines in *.cpp only. How i can count line in the *.h file too without pugixml.cpp?

```
find . -type f  -name \*.cpp -and ! -name \pugixml.cpp -exec cat '{}' + | wc -l
```

Comment: Can you clarify?  Do you mean all .h files, or just the corresponding .h files for each existing .cpp file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `-o` to look for files named `*.cpp` or `*.h`, and add parentheses for precedence. Note that I've removed the `-and` and the backslash in `\pugixml` as they were unnecessary (though harmless).

```
find . -type f \( -name \*.cpp -o -name \*.h \) ! -name pugixml.cpp -exec cat {} + | wc -l
```

Also you could reduce `find -exec cat {} + | wc -l` to simply `find -exec wc -l {} +`. That would show statistics for each individual file as well as a total count.

```
find . -type f \( -name \*.cpp -o -name \*.h \) ! -name pugixml.cpp -exec wc -l {} +
```

Comment: No command '-exec' found, did you mean:
 Command 'kexec' from package 'kexec-tools' (main)
 Command 'gexec' from package 'gexec' (universe)
 Command 'jexec' from package 'openjdk-6-jre-headless' (main)
-exec: command not found

Comment: Most versions of find support the "-exec" command. Evidently, yours doesn't. The only version I'm aware of that doesn't is on Solaris, in which case you can use gfind instead.

Comment: Make the command faster by removing the individual process for each file found:  find . -type f \( -name \*.cpp -o -name \*.h \) ! -name pugixml.cpp | xargs wc -l

Comment: @Brian Using `-exec +` tells find to only call the command once. Contrast this with `-exec \;` which invokes the command once per file.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you really actually want [sloccount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/).

Answer (score 0):

Grep it!
You know, if you want to count only ***.h** files, you will automatically exclude `pugixml.cpp`

```
sloccount --duplicates --wide --details . | grep -e "\.h$"
```

If you you really need to explicitly exclude pugi:

```
sloccount --duplicates --wide --details . | grep -e "\.h$" | grep -v -e 'pugixml.cpp'
```